# react_on_rails how to render other views from a component without using library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, react-on-rails

I've created a rails project and then integrated react with it using `react_on_rails` gem. I've made one component and placed it inside my **new.html.erb** using `react_component` helper method. Whenever this erb view renders I get the react component and after filling in the fields the component sends a POST request to `todos#create` path and the create action after saving the fields redirect to `todos#show` because of redirect_to `@todo`. The problem is that the **show.html.erb** is not rendered automatically as before. It gets returned in the response with the React component present inside.

1. How do I render the view rendered in the response using a standard way?
2. Is there any way to handle this situation without using `react-router` and using only rails defined routes.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your component sends the POST request using `fetch`, or `ajax`, instead of relying on the native behaviour of the form rendered by your React component.

You have a couple of options:

1. Submit the form natively, this way the redirect will actually redirect.
2. Have the server send a JSON response that the React component handles to update itself.